# How do you activate a feature on promotion?

Tags: feature, feature-activation

When promoting a wsp and you have 1 or more features you wish to activate as soon as promoted, how do you do so without manually activating them on the site they are deployed to?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what do you mean by "promoting a wsp"? Do you refer to classical wsp install/upgrade or are you thinking about something specific? I never heared that term before, so I want to ensure that I have understand your question.

Comment: Sounds like promoting might mean deployed??

Comment: @PaulLucas, I think so. I asked just to be on the safe side - it could be something SharePoint Online oriented, in which case I dubt I could help (never used it... yet).

Comment: sorry yes, I meant deployment of WSP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature manifest has an attribute 'ActivateOnDefault' which will trigger an activation during installation (WSP upgrade qualifies). Note that this doesn't apply to site or web scoped features. However, if you want to activate a site/web feature by default then you can do things like create a farm feature as a 'controller' which will activate these for you.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms436075.aspx